# Kill session in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 1000 records on my table,while deleting records using toad, I get a error message as

ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

I tried ,

```
alter system kill session ('214,60347');
```

but I get invalid for both attributes.In this i declared correct values,

I also tried

`alter system kill session ('214,60347#');` as `alter system kill session ('sid,serial#');`

is first query correct? or are there any other ways to kill session in oracle?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_system_kill_session.htm

Comment: Killing the session shouldn't really be your first move; hopefully you've tried to find where the locks are held, which is likely to be another session that's also issued the same delete, so you can rollback or commit that normally.

Comment: ya alex i was commit all the process and deleted the datas.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that the transaction was not committed nor rolled back. Event after the error if you are able to do one of both try it.

It would be good to add the "immediate" keyword at the end to force it right away.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ('sid,serial#') IMMEDIATE;

ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ('214,60347') IMMEDIATE;
```

Because killing the session can make a mess try to use the "disconnect" option.

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
```

Details about it can be found here:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions.php